# C++ standard library forward_list issue

Tags: c++, c++11, std, forward-list

I need some help solving the exercise 9.28 from the C++ Primer 5th edition. Here is the task:

> Write a function that takes a forward_list and
>   two additional string arguments. The function should find the first string
>   and insert the second immediately following the first. If the first string is
>   not found, then insert the second string at the end of the list.

I can't get the idea written in the book as to how `forward_list` actually works and why we indeed need it, so I'm asking for help. Below is the code I wrote which is incomplete and I need someone help me finish it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

void find_and_insert(forward_list<string>& flstr, const string& needle, const string& rplc) {

    auto curr = flstr.begin();
    auto last = flstr.end();
    bool found = false;

    while (curr != last) {

        if (*curr == needle) {

            found = true;
            // what to put here?!
            break;
        }

        // what to put here?!... 
        ++curr;
    }

    for (const auto& elem : flstr) {

        cout << elem << endl;
    }

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cout << endl;

    forward_list<string> flstring = {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Tomcat"};

    find_and_insert(flstring, "Bar", "Insertion");

    cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any suggestion to refactor the code is welcome!

Comment: Here is the documentation for forward_list: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list Let's us know what exactly you do not understand and we will help.

Comment: Ok. I will look through the docs. Thanks SergeyA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the function the following way using member function `before_begin`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>
#include <string>

void find_and_insert( std::forward_list<std::string> &lst, 
                      const std::string &src, 
                      const std::string &dest ) 
{
    auto before = lst.before_begin();
    auto first  = lst.begin();

    while ( first != lst.end() && *first != src ) ++before, ++first;

    lst.insert_after( first == lst.end() ? before : first, dest );
}

int main()
{
    std::forward_list<std::string> lst;

    find_and_insert( lst, "one", "zero" );

    for ( const std::string &s : lst ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    find_and_insert( lst, "zero", "two");

    for ( const std::string &s : lst ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    find_and_insert( lst, "zero", "one");

    for ( const std::string &s : lst ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    find_and_insert( lst, "two", "three");

    for ( const std::string &s : lst ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    find_and_insert( lst, "four", "four");

    for ( const std::string &s : lst ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
zero 
zero two 
zero one two 
zero one two three 
zero one two three four
```

Comment: It works, but it was slightly difficult for me to understand at first =). Thanks for effort Vlad!

Answer (score 2):

For the first part you need to use [`insert_after`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/insert_after).  You will pass the current iterator to it and the string to insert and it will insert that string after the current element.

As far as as inserting an element at the end that gets a little more complicated as `std::forward_list::iterator` is a [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator).  Luckily we have the [`before_begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/before_begin) which will return an iterator 1 before the beginning.  You can get capture that iterator and every time you increment `curr` you increment that iterator as well.  Once the loop is over check to see `found` is `true`.  If it is then you can use that 1 before the beginning iterator as it now points to the last element.  You will pass that to `insert_after` with the string just like you do in the while loop.

Comment: You don't actually need to check `found`. The iterator will always be good to use as insertion position. Because the requirements say that if the value is not found, the new element should be added at the end.

Comment: @5gon12eder If we don't check found how do we know it wasn't inserted in the list already?

Comment: The way I'm reading the requirement, the function would insert a duplicate in this case.

Comment: @5gon12eder *find the first string and insert the second immediately following the first. If the first string is not found, then insert the second string at the end of the list.*  This looks like you only put it at then end if the first string is not found.

Comment: Yes, but you always insert. If you find the first string, then you insert immediately after that position. And if you don't find it, you insert at the end. All you need to do is remember the position before the last item you have looked at. I don't see why you would need an additional flag.

Comment: I could explain it better with code but I kind of like the fact that you didn't spoiler the solution to the OP's homework so I don't want to do it either.

Comment: @5gon12eder OK.  I did that for that just that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, NathanOliver and 5gon12eder! I will consider both ideas ;)